# symfony2 security component issue

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony-security

I have created custom user provider in my symfony 2.3 project. In function loadUserByUsername i am calling webservice to authenticate my user. 
Now my problem is that i want to get password which was entered in login form. So i passed service container as argument by following code

```
 services:   
     webservice_user_provider:
        class: AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUserProvider
        arguments:    ['@service_container']
```

in my user provider class, i am getting a request object so that i can get password

```
public function __construct(Container $container) {
    $this->request = $container->get('request');
}
```

By doing it this way, symfony profiler/toolbar shows message "The security component is disabled". Login works fine but still the message worries me a bit. Is there any other way to get password in user provider/getting container in user provider ?

Comment: Sounds to me like you should not be writing a custom user provider, but a custom authenticator. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html for an example.

Comment: Thanks Gerry, will try your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [excelent article](http://blog.vandenbrand.org/2012/06/19/symfony2-authentication-provider-authenticate-against-webservice/) about authenticating against a webservice and someone put all that together and pushed it to [github](https://github.com/gezpage/sf2testproject/tree/webserviceauth)

Really helped me a couple of days ago.